# UICatalog (tvOS) Objective C version?

Tags: tvos

I found UICatalog (tvOS) Swift version

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016433

Anyone has found Objective C version?

Comment: What you're linking to is sample code, not documentation...

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about UICatalog (tvOS) ObjC version source code.

Answer (score 0):

There is none and won't be. Apple is 'all-in' with Swift and seldomly does anything new in Objective-C these days. Luckily it doesn't matter much though, since you can very easily transform a Swift program into Objective-C. If you can't, you better start acquiring that skill, since Swift is getting more popular every day.